# AntiForgeryToken Preventing Users From Logging In On Certain Mobile Devices

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, csrf, antiforgerytoken

My process is very simple; the user logs in with a login form.  The login form does a post, and defines an `@Html.AntiForgeryToken`.  On the server, the action method defines `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` to validate the token provided.  It's the default microsoft account login setup logic, and not much has been changed with that.

The following is the error some users are getting:

> Anti forgery token is meant for user "" but the current user is
>   "username"

And is preventing users from logging into the system.  This is only happening for some users on certain mobile devices, so it's very isolated.  Also, it's a simple as just logging in; it's not any post operations after the fact like I've seen in other posts on the issue, so it's a very strange issue to resolve.

Any idea why certain mobile devices would reject this?

Answer (score 0):

this mainly happens because the mechanism of generating the token will read the the current username and consider it as input when generating the AntiForgeryToken value which is usually a blank username before the login complete.

When your user login successfully, now the username value has a "value", so the old token will not pass the security check performed by the asp.net runtime and so your mentioned error will showup.

one way is to suppress your application to ignore including the username as part of the generated token by adding the following line to your Application_Start inside your Global file:

`AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks = true.`

Comment: Do you foresee any security implications with that decision, as user name is what makes the encrypted key unique...  It seems weird that it does work for some users, but not others.

Comment: I think the only achievable security concern here is exactly the same like if you consider the username as part of the inputs. any attacker needs to gain access to TWO things: your `AntiForgeryToken` value as well as your coupled Cookie. without this correct combination, you should be safe.